# Java data structure to allow boolean flags on objects and sorting?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I wish to have a set of Objects and booleans that mark an object as "visited" or not. Naturally I thought of Map that will tell me if an object is already visited or not. But I want them to be sorted too, so that whenever I ask "Who is the 'smallest' object visited?". The calculation wouldn't be too difficult, max O(n) on that data structure.
In my very specific case I'm asking about Date object, but it's irrelevant.
Objects can be added to that data structure at any moment, and will be entered with 'false' values.

Comment: do you need something like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html ?

Comment: One way to achieve it would be to write a custom comparator for your object and use a TreeSet to keep the visited data in sorted order. Maintain the visited and unvisited date objects separately.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `SortedSet`. When an object is visited, add it to the set. To find out if an object was visited, just use `set.contains()`. To find the smallest object:

```
T smallest = set.isEmpty() ? null : set.iterator().next();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map of `<Boolean, TreeSet<Object>>`, where you keep all of the visited objects in the set mapped to `true` and visa-versa (assuming you're not dealing with duplicate objects). I believe that insertion into a `TreeSet` runs in O(n) time, and to get the "smallest" object visited, you would use `first()`, which runs in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is guava's TreeMultiset, please read about the Multiset, a TreeMultiset implementation maintains the ordering of its elements. You can write a custom Comparator - in first place you could have most frequently visited object.

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

If you use it you won't have structures like

```
  Collection<Something, Something>
```

and also sorting would be out of the box after implementing a Comparator.